# input not working in jQuery mobile

Tags: php, jquery, css, html, jquery-mobile

I am creating a form using jQuery mobile but when I try to enter anything focus is not set on any fields.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
    <title>Lets Share</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
    <link href="css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/themes/default/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src='js/jquery-ui.min.js'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $( document ).on( "pageinit", "#page", function() {
            $( document ).on( "swipeleft swiperight", "#page", function( e ) {
                if ( $.mobile.activePage.jqmData( "panel" ) !== "open" ) {
                    if ( e.type === "swiperight" && e.swipestart.coords[0] <= 50 ) {
                        $( "#navpanel" ).panel( "open" );
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        .ui-li-static.ui-collapsible > .ui-collapsible-heading {
            margin: 0;
        }
        .ui-li-static.ui-collapsible {
            padding: 0;
        }
        .ui-li-static.ui-collapsible > .ui-collapsible-heading > .ui-btn {
            border-top-width: 0;
        }
        .ui-li-static.ui-collapsible > .ui-collapsible-heading.ui-collapsible-heading-collapsed > .ui-btn,
        .ui-li-static.ui-collapsible > .ui-collapsible-content {
            border-bottom-width: 0;
        }
        *:not(input,textarea) {
            -webkit-touch-callout: none;
            -webkit-user-select: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="loading_div" style="display:block;" >
    <div class="loading_image">
        <div class="loading_image_cont"> <img src="images/loading.gif" alt="Loading..." /></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="page" data-role="page">
    <div data-role="panel" id="navpanel"  data-theme="a" data-display="push" data-position="left">
        <ul data-role="listview" data-shadow="true">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">My Profile</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Edit Profile</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Change Password</a></li>
            <li data-role="collapsible" data-iconpos="right" data-inset="false">
                <h2>My Post Trips</h2>
                <ul data-role="listview" data-theme="b">
                    <li><a href="#">Event Tickets</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Fast Food</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Fitness</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Home Improvement</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Hotels and lodging</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Household Services</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Medical</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li data-role="collapsible" data-iconpos="right" data-inset="false">
                <h2>My Searched Trips</h2>
                <ul data-role="listview" data-theme="b">
                    <li><a href="#">Event Tickets</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Fast Food</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Fitness</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Home Improvement</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Hotels and lodging</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Household Services</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Medical</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="">Logout</a></li>
            <li><a href="login.html">Login/Signup</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="header" data-role="header"  data-add-back-btn="true" data-position="fixed">
        <!--<a href="#menu" class="myMenu"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>-->
        <a id="bars-button" data-icon="bars"  class="ui-btn-left" href="#navpanel">Menu</a>
        <div class="logo"><h1><a href="#">Lets Share</a></h1></div>
        <a data-icon="bars" class="ui-btn-right" onclick="viewFilter()"><i class="fa fa-filter"></i></a>
       <!-- <a href="#" class="myFilter"><i class="fa fa-filter"></i></a>-->
    </div>
    <div class="content ui-content" data-role="main"  >
        <!-- all trips listing here -->
        <div id="all-trips" class="swipe-pagination contact-page-class"></div>
        <!-- Trip details here  -->
        <div id="trip-details" class="contact-page-class"></div>
        <!-- filter start -->
        <div id="trip-filter" class="contact-page-class" >
            <form method="post">
                <div class="filter-form ui-body ui-body-a">
                    <div  data-role="fieldcontain">
                        <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" >
                            <legend>Pool Type:</legend>
                            <input type="radio" name="FormData[type]" id="radio-choice-1" value="2" checked="checked" />
                            <label for="radio-choice-1">Car Pooling</label>
                            <input type="radio" name="FormData[type]" id="radio-choice-2" value="1"  />
                            <label for="radio-choice-2">Taxi Sharing</label>
                        </fieldset>
                    </div>
                    <div  data-role="fieldcontain">
                        <label for="FormData[i_am]" class="select">Shipping method:</label>
                        <select name="FormData[i_am]" id="i_am" data-native-menu="false" >
                            <option value="standard">Driver</option>
                            <option value="rush">Passenger</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ui-body" data-role="fieldcontain">
                        <fieldset class="ui-grid-a">
                            <div class="ui-block-a">
                                <label for="FormData[from_address]" class="select">From:</label>
                                <select name="FormData[from_address]" id="from" data-native-menu="false">
                                    <option value="">Select From</option>
                                    <optgroup label="City &amp; South West">
                                        <option value="1">Boat Quay / Raffles Place</option>
                                        <option value="2">Chinatown / Tanjong Pagar</option>
                                        <option value="3">Alexandra / Commonwealth</option>
                                        <option value="4">HarbourFront / Telok Blangah</option>
                                        <option value="5">Buona Vista / West Coast</option>
                                        <option value="6">City Hall / Clarke Quay</option>
                                        <option value="7">Beach Road / Bugis / Rochor</option>
                                        <option value="8">Farrer Park / Serangoon Road</option>
                                    </optgroup>
                                    <optgroup label="Orchard / Holland">
                                        <option value="9">Orchard / River Valley</option>
                                        <option value="10">Tanglin / Holland</option>
                                    </optgroup>
                                    <optgroup label="Newton / Bt. Timah">
                                        <option value="11">Newton / Novena</option>
                                        <option value="12">Clementi / Upper Bukit Timah</option>
                                    </optgroup>
                                    <optgroup label="Balestier / Geylang">
                                        <option value="13">Balestier / Toa Payoh</option>
                                        <option value="14">Macpherson / Potong Pasir</option>
                                        <option value="15">Eunos / Geylang / Paya Lebar</option>
                                    </optgroup>
                                    <optgroup label="East Coast">
                                        <option value="16">East Coast / Marine Parade</option>
                                        <option value="17">Bedok / Upper East Coast</option>
                                    </optgroup>
                                    <optgroup label="Changi / Pasir Ris">
                                        <option value="18">Changi Airport / Changi Village</option>
                                        <option value="19">Pasir Ris / Tampines</option>
                                    </optgroup>
                                    <optgroup label="Serangoon / Thomson">
                                        <option value="20">Hougang / Punggol / Sengkang</option>
                                        <option value="21">Ang Mo Kio / Bishan / Thomson</option>
                                    </optgroup>
                                    <optgroup label="West">
                                        <option value="22">Boon Lay / Jurong / Tuas</option>
                                        <option value="23">Bukit Batok / Bukit Panjang</option>
                                        <option value="24">Choa Chu Kang / Tengah</option>
                                    </optgroup>
                                    <optgroup label="North">
                                        <option value="25">Admiralty / Woodlands</option>
                                        <option value="26">Manda / Upper Thomson</option>
                                        <option value="27">Sembawang / Yishun</option>
                                        <option value="28">Seletar / Yio Chu Kang</option>
                                    </optgroup>
                                    <optgroup label="Malaysia">
                                        <option value="29">Johor</option>
                                    </optgroup>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="ui-block-b">
                                <label for="FormData[zipcode_from]" class="select">Zip code</label>
                                <input type="text" name="FormData[zipcode_from]" id="name" value="" placeholder="Zipcode From"  /></div>
                        </fieldset>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ui-body" data-role="fieldcontain">
                        <fieldset class="ui-grid-a">
                            <div class="ui-block-a">
                                <label for="FormData[to_address]" class="select">To:</label>
                                <select name="FormData[to_address]" data-native-menu="false">
                                    <option value="">Select From</option>
                                    <optgroup label="City &amp; South West">
                                        <option value="1">Boat Quay / Raffles Place</option>
                                        <option value="2">Chinatown / Tanjong Pagar</option>
                                        <option value="3">Alexandra / Commonwealth</option>
                                        <option value="4">HarbourFront / Telok Blangah</option>
                                        <option value="5">Buona Vista / West Coast</option>
                                        <option value="6">City Hall / Clarke Quay</option>
                                        <option value="7">Beach Road / Bugis / Rochor</option>
                                        <option value="8">Farrer Park / Serangoon Road</option>
                                    </optgroup>
                                    <optgroup label="Orchard / Holland">
                                        <option value="9">Orchard / River Valley</option>
                                        <option value="10">Tanglin / Holland</option>
                                    </optgroup>
                                    <optgroup label="Newton / Bt. Timah">
                                        <option value="11">Newton / Novena</option>
                                        <option value="12">Clementi / Upper Bukit Timah</option>
                                    </optgroup>
                                    <optgroup label="Balestier / Geylang">
                                        <option value="13">Balestier / Toa Payoh</option>
                                        <option value="14">Macpherson / Potong Pasir</option>
                                        <option value="15">Eunos / Geylang / Paya Lebar</option>
                                    </optgroup>
                                    <optgroup label="East Coast">
                                        <option value="16">East Coast / Marine Parade</option>
                                        <option value="17">Bedok / Upper East Coast</option>
                                    </optgroup>
                                    <optgroup label="Changi / Pasir Ris">
                                        <option value="18">Changi Airport / Changi Village</option>
                                        <option value="19">Pasir Ris / Tampines</option>
                                    </optgroup>
                                    <optgroup label="Serangoon / Thomson">
                                        <option value="20">Hougang / Punggol / Sengkang</option>
                                        <option value="21">Ang Mo Kio / Bishan / Thomson</option>
                                    </optgroup>
                                    <optgroup label="West">
                                        <option value="22">Boon Lay / Jurong / Tuas</option>
                                        <option value="23">Bukit Batok / Bukit Panjang</option>
                                        <option value="24">Choa Chu Kang / Tengah</option>
                                    </optgroup>
                                    <optgroup label="North">
                                        <option value="25">Admiralty / Woodlands</option>
                                        <option value="26">Manda / Upper Thomson</option>
                                        <option value="27">Sembawang / Yishun</option>
                                        <option value="28">Seletar / Yio Chu Kang</option>
                                    </optgroup>
                                    <optgroup label="Malaysia">
                                        <option value="29">Johor</option>
                                    </optgroup>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="ui-block-b">
                                <label for="FormData[zipcode_to]" class="select">Zip code</label>
                                <input type="text" name="FormData[zipcode_to]" value="ewr" placeholder="Zipcode To"   /></div>
                        </fieldset>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="getIntouch">
            See how we can help. Contact us today. <br>
            <a href="" class="orangeBtn">Get in Touch</a>
        </div>
        <div class="socialLinks">
            <a class="fa fa-facebook-square"></a>
            <a class="fa fa-twitter-square"></a>
            <a class="fa fa-google-plus-square"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- alert pop up  Success / error / warning -->
    <div data-role="popup" id="successAlert" data-overlay-theme="b" data-theme="a" class="ui-corner-all" data-dismissible="false" data-transition="pop">
        <a href="#" data-rel="back" data-role="button" data-theme="a" data-icon="delete" data-iconpos="notext" class="ui-btn-right">Close</a>
        <div data-role="content" data-theme="d" class="ui-corner-bottom ui-content">
            <div data-role="header" data-theme="a" class="ui-corner-top ui-corner-all" id="successType" >
                <h1 style="color: #f8ffff" id="alertTitle">SUCCESS</h1>
            </div>
            <p class="ui-title" id="successMessage">You successfully login.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- alert pop up  Success / error / warning -->
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var sitePath="http://192.168.0.10/letsshare/";
    var debugMode=1; //Set 0 for LIVE mode
    var AuthToken = "";
    var perPage = 3;
    var homeDiv="home_div"; //It is pending to define according to login user Type
    var backDivsStack=new Array();
    var weekDays  = ["Mon","Tues","Wed","Thur","Fri","SAT","Sun"];
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $( "body" ).disableSelection();
        //AllTrips("all-trips",1);
        viewFilter();
    });

    function viewFilter(){
        displayDiv("trip-filter");
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

If I add onClick="this.focus()" in any text box then its working. But directly when I click by mouse it not working.

Comment: Works for me, but I don't have exactly same versions of jQuery libraries (using those provided by Google). Also you have "index.js" (unknown to us) that can be the culprit. Comment the "index.js" out and test again.

Comment: Please also use for example Google Chrome to see if you have any errors on your page. I suppose that you might have some javascript error due to the mysterious "index.js".

Comment: @RistoVälimäki index.js is use for phonegap.  when i remove my main jqyery library then all things start working very well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works in Chrome as well as IE.

But for Firefox, I needed to comment out your code line to get the selection working:
$("body").disableSelection();

EDIT:
Please see following link about the issue and other possible workarounds:
https://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-ui-sortable-disableselection-firefox-issue-with-inputs